# Entity Framework Core 2.1 throwing ArgumentException on left join

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I recently upgraded my project from .NET Core 2.0 to 2.1. I use Entity Framework Core and have several LINQ expressions that include left joins. The following code is an example:

```
var tickets = (from ticket in dbContext.Tickets
               join member in dbContext.Members on ticket.MemberID equals member.ID into memberLEFT
               from member in memberLEFT.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join memberType in dbContext.MemberTypes on member.MemberTypeID equals memberType.ID into memberTypeLEFT
               from memberType in memberTypeLEFT.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select memberType)
              .ToList();
```

If .NET Core 2.0, this line executed with no exceptions. In .NET Core 2.1, it's throwing the following ArgumentException:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Field
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]].Inner'
>   is not defined for type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]''

If I change the LINQ to perform inner joins instead of left, then it executes no problem. The joins need to be left joins though, so I can't just update all of my code to do inner joins.

Does anyone know why EF Core 2.1 is now throwing ArgumentExecptions when performing left joins, and how to get around the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you creating your joins on your own instead of using the EF releationship model. I've taken your example and changed it a little bit.

**Models:**

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? MemberID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(MemberID))]
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? MemberTypeID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(MemberTypeID))]
    public MemberType MemberType { get; set; }
}

public class MemberType
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

To define an outer join just make the foreign-key nullable.

When you've created your models like this you can just include the properties in your query:

```
Tickets = (from t in _dbContext.Tickets
              .Include(t => t.Member)
                  .ThenInclude(m => m.MemberType)
            select t).ToList();
```

The generated sql looks like this:

```
SELECT [t].[ID], [t].[Description], [t].[MemberID], [t.Member].[ID], [t.Member]. 
    [Description], [t.Member].[MemberTypeID], [t.Member.MemberType].[ID], 
    [t.Member.MemberType].[Description]
FROM [Tickets] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [Members] AS [t.Member] ON [t].[MemberID] = [t.Member].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [MemberTypes] AS [t.Member.MemberType] ON [t.Member].[MemberTypeID] = 
    [t.Member.MemberType].[ID]
```

Hope that helps your issue.

Comment: Yes! Another navigation properties evangelist!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I do have my models defined as you laid out and often do use Includes and ThenIncludes in my code. I thought it was better practice to use joins opposed to Includes/ThenIncludes when possible because I thought the generated SQL query was more efficient that way. Looking at the generated SQL from your example though, it looks like Includes/ThenIncludes are just as (if not more) efficient than writing the joins. I'll start using the Includes/ThenIncludes and see if there is any noticeable performance differences, and if not, I'll just start using them when possible.

Comment: You don't need the ForeignKey attributes or the ID properties. EF is smart enough to know that you want a foreign key when you have a property of another custom type.

Comment: This answer is pretty much exactly what I would have added - but I was beaten to it! The only other thing I would have suggested is to move away from the DataAnnotationAttributes and use the EF fluent configuration instead.. Its much cleaner

Answer (score 9):

From **tools > Options** check `Enable Just My code`

[image]

Comment: This isnt helpful

Comment: @RobertPerry it's, the reason the error is there at first place and is that you are debugging the EfCore internal library. you disable this and you get error related to yours. plus it's an EfCore internal bug that they will resolve in version 3.0

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you. Do you know the bug number related to this?

Comment: happy you find it helpful, sorry but I can't remember where was it, but it's something with the same bug in the issue tracker and they set a milestone for version 3.0

Comment: This must be the right answer, I had the same issue. But because the setting was not selected, i was getting that exception. when I checked it, the exception disappeared. it turn out that this exception is something related to EF core and doesn't affect the application flow.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best solution i found here :[https://stackoverflow.com/a/58017017/1983909]
from stackoverflow user: Hakan Çelik MK1

---

Using Visual Studio 2019 (I assume 2017 too) you can disable this exception just for System.Linq.Expressions.

The way to do it is as follows :

- Open Exception Settings window. Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings (Ctrl+Alt+E)
- There is a search box at the top right of the window, type "System.ArgumentException" in it
- You will see the exception listed in the window, right click on it and select "Edit Conditions" from the menu
- Edit Conditions allows you to set the conditions for the debugger to break when the exception is thrown
- From left to right, select Module Name, select Not Equals and type "System.Linq.Expressions.dll" in the edit box at the right
  Click OK and close the window