# System.Linq.Expressions exception thrown when using FirstOrDefault in .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am receiving ~300+ exceptions that are spammed in my server output labeled:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll
```

The query I am using is as follows:

```
Account account = _accountContext.Account.
     Include(i => i.Currency).
     Include(i => i.Unlocks).
     Include(i => i.Settings).
     Include(i => i.Friends).
     FirstOrDefault(a => a.FacebookUserID == facebookUserID);
```

Eventually the exceptions stop generating, it shows a large query in the output window, and everything continues as normal.

If I change the query to the following I do not experience the exception:

```
IQueryable<Account> account = _accountContext.Account.
     Include(i => i.Currency).
     Include(i => i.Unlocks).
     Include(i => i.Settings).
     Include(i => i.Friends).
     Where(a => a.FacebookUserID == facebookUserID);
```

However, if I call anything such as `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, etc on the `IQueryable<Account>` variable the exceptions start up again and then stop after ~300.

These exceptions are stalling user logins upwards of 30 seconds or more. The duration of exceptions grows with the amount of data being returned from the database.

I use the Account object by passing it around the server to perform varying maintenance tasks on it and then eventually sending the object client-side where I have it being deserialized into the client-side version of the Account class.

Does anyone know what could be causing these internal exceptions and how I might be able to eliminate or mitigate them?

Here is my output log:
[image]

Below is the exception message:
The `AccountStatistics` isn't listed in the query above because there are about 20 some includes and I shorthanded the include list for brevity.

```
Field 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Project.Models.Account,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.AccountStatistics]].Inner' is not defined for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Project.Models.Account,Project.Models.AccountStatistics]'
```

There is no inner exception.
I double checked my database and I have an entry for the user and all of their fields are filled with valid data.

Account Class (Edited for brevity)

```
public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        public AccountCurrency Currency { get; set; }
        public AccountProgression Progression { get; set; }
        public AccountSettings Settings { get; set; }
        public AccountStatistics Statistics { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AccountFriendEntry> Friends { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AccountUnlockedGameEntry> Unlocks{ get; set; }
    }
```

Account Statistics class

```
public class AccountStatistics
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public int LoginCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

Keys for the Account Statistics table

[image]

```
   migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AccountStatistics",
            columns: table => new
            {
                AccountID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                LoginCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                LastLoginTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                CreationDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AccountStatistics", x => x.AccountID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AccountStatistics_Accounts_AccountID",
                    column: x => x.AccountID,
                    principalTable: "Accounts",
                    principalColumn: "ID",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

**Edit 9001**

After doing some testing I've realized the exception only occurs when chaining includes.

This will cause an exception:

```
Account account = _accountContext.Account.
     Include(i => i.Currency).
     Include(i => i.Unlocks).
     Include(i => i.Settings).
     Include(i => i.Friends).
     FirstOrDefault(a => a.FacebookUserID == facebookUserID);
```

This will NOT cause an exception:

```
Account account = _accountContext.Account.
     Include(i => i.Currency).
     FirstOrDefault(a => a.FacebookUserID == facebookUserID);
```

It does not matter if its currency and unlock, friends and currency, settings, and statistics. Any combination of includes (2 or more) causes the exception to happen.

**Edit 9002**

Here are my results of the following query:

```
var acct = _accountContext.Account
     .Where(a => a.FacebookUserID == facebookUserID)
     .Select(x => new { Account = x, x.Currency, x.Settings }).ToList();
```

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Field 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Project.Models.Account,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.AccountSettings]].Inner' is not defined for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Project.Models.Account,Project.Models.AccountSettings]''
```

I feel like this is treating `AccountSettings` as a collection when it's a single field reference.

**Edit Final:**
I never found a fix for this issue. I re-created all the tables and such in another environment and it works just fine. Not a very ideal solution to blow away all tables, classes, and migrations, but it's the only thing that fixed the issue.

Comment: It's often helpful when trying to debug exceptions if you provide a detailed stack trace from the exception.

Comment: Are you tried to remove those Include in the expression? Perhaps the problem come from the relations among the entities. If you remove one by one, maybe you can insulate the problematic entity

Comment: @StriplingWarrior There is no stack trace of the exception. The output log just spams that exception line above about 300 times. The entire process is surrounded by a try/catch but it never throws. I'm guessing this has something to do with the internals of that .dll

Comment: @mnieto I did try a manual .Where.Select with a few specified columns selected but the moment I convert that into an object, etc. It still happens.

Comment: In VS, while you are debugging, if you go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings, you can tell VS to break on an `ArgumentException` immediately.  Then you can trigger the errors, and debug your code.  The debugger will probably stop somewhere in non-user code, so reviewing the call stack will be needed.

Comment: It's possible that EF trows one exception per row tried to materialize. Revise the entity relations and any possible conversion

Comment: That's a good point.  `Where` does not materialize your entities, and all of the methods that cause you problems, do.  You might consider reviewing how your entities are mapped to the database.  Something might be mapped wrong.

Comment: If I were to run an IQueryable version of this and then inspect the result in VS it will properly return all the data in the intellisense window, but actual the conversion causes the exceptions.

Comment: Can you post the definition / mapping for the AccountStatistics class? Based on the exception details it looks like EF is having issues with mapping the relationship to this class. I'm assuming it should have an AccountID FK to reference back to the Account.

Comment: @StevePy I believe I've added what you were looking for. If not, let me know. It does seem to have the proper FK reference to the account table.

Comment: Hmm, nothing there stands out. It's a 1-to-1 on the same PK. Do you have explicit mappings for this relationship? With the AccountSettings, does this too use AccountID as the PK? What happens if you temporarily remove the AccountStatistics mapping from account? [NotMapped]

Comment: @StevePy AccountSettings looks exactly like AccountStatistics. I did some more testing last night and it seems the exception is only thrown when I do multiple includes. If I only have one included statement I get no exception. The moment I add a second include - it doesn't seem to matter the combination - I get that same exception.

Comment: That seems very odd. Try a `.Select(x => new { Account = x, x.Currency, x.Unlocks, x.Settings, x.Friends, x.Settings, x.Statistics }).ToList()` after your `.Where()` without any `.Include()` statements. I'd be curious if this returned the data without exception, or it might shed some light on a problem with the mapping that is tripping up `.Include()`

Comment: @StevePy Posted my results under edit 9002. I tried the statement with only `x.Currency` and it passed, however, adding any number of extra `x.TableNames` and the exceptions come back. 

When I don't do the `ToList()` and just inspect the results inside intellisense, it takes a moment and then shows me the proper results. Not sure if the exception would be thrown inside the results view of intellisense.

Comment: Seems like it may be a bug or "feature" of EF Core, or something tucked in somewhere in the mappings. Given that set of entities and mappings, can you extract them into a new project and try it with EF 6.2?  If it works with EF 6 against the same tables/mappings then this would narrow it down to Core and possibly something that can be raised. If it doesn't work with 6.2, you may get  a different exception that might shed some further light.

Comment: show model configuration of `AccountSetting` and `Account`

Comment: Aren't there some decorators you are supposed to add to your model properties with foreign key constraints? I'm not 100% on if they are strictly necessary or not, but might be in terms of the IQueryable implementation.

Comment: Same issue after upgrading to vs2019, issue took a few days to appear though. Enabling just my code was a fine trick

Answer (score 22):

I was getting this issue when debugging whilst my colleagues weren't. After much head scratching we discovered I was the only one with the **Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code** setting unticked.

Ticking it hide the thousands of `Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll` errors in the Output window, the code went back to normal speed and I could happily live on with my head buried in the sand.

Comment: Had same situation with me. Just did Enabled Just My code worked.

Comment: Be careful turning this on, for web developers this means your breakpoints inside Razor pages etc. won't be hit anymore... The messages only appear while you are in `Debug` mode, when you build your application in `Release` mode the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` statements (from `System.Linq.Expressions.dll` library) aren't even included in the final code so this shouldn't impact performance. Correct answer, but be sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: I have the same problem even for Release builds

Comment: I prefer just unchecking "Break when this exception type is thrown"

Answer (score 5):

@Sean Malone's answer did the trick for me.
Checking the option "Enable Just My Code" in Visual Studio, Menu Tools => Options => Debugging => General

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. It's a bug related to Debugging (see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12548) and  will only be fixed in version 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add my 2 cents here.

It appears we have to live with this until 3.0 but, disabling all exceptions from other code is not a good idea. You may miss something important during debugging.

I'm on .NET Core 2.2.7 but, this still comes up from time to time.

Using Visual Studio 2019 (I assume 2017 too) you can disable this exception just for System.Linq.Expressions.

The way to do it is as follows :

- Open Exception Settings window. Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings (Ctrl+Alt+E)
- There is a search box at the top right of the window, type "System.ArgumentException" in it
- You will see the exception listed in the window, right click on it and select "Edit Conditions" from the menu
- Edit Conditions allows you to set the conditions for the debugger to break when the exception is thrown
- From left to right, select Module Name, select Not Equals and type "System.Linq.Expressions.dll" in the edit box at the right
- Click OK and close the window

The same problem will not bother you again, but you will be able to catch the same exception from other places. I find this quite helpful during debugging.

Cheers.